# Model.includes(:property) seemingly not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm starting a small Rails project to register iOS devices here at the office, just to learn the framework, and I've come across the following problem:

Given two models "Device" and "Owner" with the following associations:

```
class Owner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :devices
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner
  belongs_to :os_version
  belongs_to :device_type
end
```

Schemas are:

```
CREATE TABLE "devices" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    "uuid" varchar(255), 
    "imei" varchar(255), 
    "device_type_id" integer, 
    "label" varchar(255), 
    "os_version_id" integer, 
    "owner_id" integer, 
    "created_at" datetime, 
    "updated_at" datetime, 
    "serial" varchar(255)
);
CREATE TABLE "owners" (
    "id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
    "first_name" varchar(255), 
    "last_name" varchar(255), 
    "username" varchar(255), 
    "created_at" datetime, 
    "updated_at" datetime
);
```

I'm trying to get a controller to eagerly fetch an Owner with all its Devices, so I tried the following:

```
class OwnerController < ApplicationController

  def list
    @owners = Owner.includes(:devices).all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render :xml=>@owners } 
      format.any(:json, :html) { render :json => @owners }
    end
  end
end
```

The controller successfully lists all owners, but the devices are nowhere to be found.

I've also tried using default scope in the Owner class, but still no good.

When using `rails console`, any query using `Owner.include(:devices)` fails to return device information, but `Owner.first.devices` has everything in it.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify that your XML and JSON views should include the devices associations:

```
format.xml { render :xml => @owners.to_xml(:include => :devices) }
```

Or, in Rails 3, to make things a little simpler:

```
class OwnerController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :json, :xml

  def list
    @owners = Owner.includes(:devices).all
    respond_with @owners, :include => :devices
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, the XML and JSON renders don't render associates by default.

For XML, you'll have to explicitly define which associations you want rendered:

```
format.xml  { render :xml => @owners.to_xml(:include => :devices) }
```

The same principle (different syntax) applies to JSON rendering.

HTH